# Finding the volume of a tank in VBA given the radius, height, and depth

Tags: excel, vba, function

I am having trouble finding the volume of a tank for an Excel VBA course; I am to make a VBA function, which I input the radius, height, and depth of the tank, and receive the volume. Here is a picture for a better understanding:

[image: The tank function instructions]

This is the code I currently have, which the course tells me is incorrect:

```
    Option Explicit

Function tank(R As Double, d As Double, H As Double) As Double

Dim pi As Double

pi = Application.WorksheetFunction.pi()

If d <= R Then

tank = pi * d ^ 2 / 3 * (3 * R - d)

ElseIf R < d And d <= H - R Then

tank = 2 / 3 * pi * R ^ 3 + pi * R ^ 2 * (d - R)

ElseIf H - R < d And d <= H Then

tank = 4 / 3 * pi * R ^ 3 + pi * R ^ 2 * (H - 2 * R) - pi * (H - d) ^ 2 / 3 * (3 * R - H + d)

End If

End Function
```

Could anyone help me with this problem? (I am using a macro provided by my course instructor, which does not tell me what is wrong, but if it is wrong or correct.)

Comment: What is your problem? I'd switch `V`for `tank` though on your if statement

Comment: The problem is that in VBA, a statement like `H - R < d <= H` is invalid.  You have to split that into two separate comparisons: `ElseIf H - R < d And d <= H Then` for example.  You should be able to apply the same change to your other similar statement.

Comment: tigeravatar - I have changed my code to follow your example of valid compound inequalities, however the problem has not been solved; I still receive the same results from running the function.

Comment: Check those symbols.  the second formula has an error.

Comment: Ugh. I can't unsee the Dr.Mario pill now.

Comment: Ryan B - I have fixed that error, however the function seems to remain incorrect. The code provided is now fully updated according to the comments' suggestions.

Comment: We need some values of R/D/H and expected results.  Which of the 3 legs fail? All?

Comment: donPablo - I do not have any values and their expected results, and I do not know which of the three legs fail. The way I am checking if the function is correct is by using another macro (password protected) provided by my course instructor which tells me if the function is incorrect. The only output I receive from that macro is "Tank function Incorrect. Please try again."

Comment: The way to do this is to implement the 3 calculations in Excel formulas (or grab a calculator), give each a handful of `r`, `d` and `h` inputs, see what the *expected output* is, then compare the output of your function with the same inputs.

Comment: Please supply the triple of values that is failing

Comment: Are your function's parameters in the incorrect order? Your assignment calls for `Tank(R, H, d)` and you've written it as `Tank(R, d, H)`. The order of parameters will completely change the outcome.

Comment: Thank you dwirony, the function now works due to the correct order of the variables.

Answer (score 6):

As answered by dwirony in the comments, my assignment called for tank(R,H,d) and my function was tank(R,d,H) which changed the outcome. Thank you for everyone who helped, the function now works. Here is the working code:

```
Option Explicit

Function tank(R As Double, H As Double, d As Double) As Double

Dim pi As Double

pi = Application.WorksheetFunction.pi()

If d <= R Then

tank = pi * d ^ 2 / 3 * (3 * R - d)

ElseIf R < d And d <= H - R Then

tank = 2 / 3 * pi * R ^ 3 + pi * R ^ 2 * (d - R)

ElseIf H - R < d And d <= H Then

tank = 4 / 3 * pi * R ^ 3 + pi * R ^ 2 * (H - 2 * R) - pi * (H - d) ^ 2 / 3 * (3 * R - H + d)

End If

End Function
```